# Как нажать Ctrl+S в selenium python с помощью библиотеки keyboard

Tags: python, selenium, python-keyboard

Брожу по сайту. Надо сохранить файл. Использую код:

`keyboard.press('Ctrl + s')`

Код не ломается. Значит, что-то нажимается. Но почему-то не Ctrl + s. Как поправить?
Допбиблиотеки подключать не хочется. Можно ли сделать это библиотекой keyboard

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/

Comment: Ещё тут есть - пример https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-to-press-ctrl-plusc-on-a-page-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: Решил вопрос, импортировав новую библиотеку pyautogui и прописав:
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','s')